# Cocoapods always install old React (0.11.0)

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I have a problem when I run `pod install` Pod always downgrade React `Installing React 0.11.0 (was 0.55.4)`

my pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
platform :ios, '9.0'
project 'BunteMobile.xcodeproj'
target 'BunteMobile' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for BunteMobile
  pod 'Adjust', '~> 4.8.3'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.7'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.0'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~>  3.9'

  pod 'lottie-ios', :path => '../node_modules/lottie-ios'

  pod 'lottie-react-native', :path => '../node_modules/lottie-react-native'

  target 'BunteMobileTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I read about some solution when I defined react folder from `node_modules` but this solution doesn't work for me too.

I put into podfile this:

```
pod 'yoga', path: './node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
```

but still doesn't work. Downgrade disappear but when I try to build it, I have this error:

```
/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTConvert.h:17:9: could not build module 'yoga'
```

I tried the same profile as official RN doc (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) but still same error.

---

#### Solution

I added this into my podfile:

```
# Pods for React-Native start
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
```

#### (update 2019)Solution 2 (react-native 0.61+): add this to pod file

```
  # Pods for React-Native start
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
```

Comment: Did you try to use pod repo update and pod update before pod install ?

Comment: i tried it and i still have a problem with yoga:  `'algorithm' file not found`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `node_modules` lines from pod file and add the library manually in xCode.

I observed that when you run `react-native link <someLibrary>` sometimes RN automatically adds that library as pod dependency.

In my case this error showed up for react-native-webview.

To fix it:

**I just removed the `node_modules/react-native-webview` line from the pod file** and then

**Added that library in xCode near the other libraries**

Drag `node_modules/some_library/ios/RNCWebView.xcodeproj` into project library files

[image]

Add the library dependencies in `build phases link binary with libraries`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're integrating RN into an existing native app, you'll want your podfile to look roughly like [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#configuring-cocoapods-dependencies). That is, you will specify the path to React dependency by `pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native' ...`

Are you developing a greenfield RN app? If so, you probably don't want to have `pod 'lottie-react-native', :path => '../node_modules/lottie-react-native'` in your podfile because it likely causes the trouble you're having.

Instead, go back to what your repo looked like before running `react-native link lottie-react-native`. This command likely added the `pod 'lottie-react-native', :path => '../node_modules/lottie-react-native'` line into your podfile. Now, you can follow manual installation instructions (that I see are not there, but you can check [these](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#manual), it will be the same thing) or you can do the following: remove `lottie-react-native.podspec` from `node_modules/lottie-react-native` and only then run `react-native link lottie-react-native`. The dependency won't be added to podfile but instead linked into the binary as a static lib.